# Game programming in C, where do I get started?

Tags: game-design, c

I started programming about 6 months back and have a decent knowledge in how to code in C. I have mainly used it to implement elementary algorithms or solve Project Euler questions (reached 50 now :) ) What I really want to learn since a long time is game programming. Ie make simple 2D games like snake, or pocket tanks. By simple, I no way mean the amount of work or effort it's going to take to make these games

I've tried searching the net but have had no luck with that. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

What exactly will I need to learn? Where do I start?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the type of question this site is for, it'll likely get closed. Start with tutorials, perhaps something that recreates a simple game like one you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The question here is what kind of thing is it that you are looking for. You can either go all-in programmer using SDL/Allegro and coding pretty much everything yourself. You can try the intermediate libraries (engines) that give you sprite management and other algorithms much more streamlined and optimized. If you just want to make games because you have one big idea, GameMaker/Construct is the way to go. They give you everything streamlined except the game logic, which is based off a scripting language you can easily learn to make complex stuff and cool effects.